# Optimisations and performance penalty (or lack) for replacing macros with static constexpr member from templated struct

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, macros, constexpr

A short description of what is happening:

The goal is to generalise some code I have. Long story short there is a base class `base` that manages an `std::array<unsigned long long,N_DIM_IDX>`. Classes build on classes build that build on classes... build on `base`. The classes have methods that do a lot of checking for set bits, shifting and flipping bits, and counting set bits of `base`. The `std::array` is basically extending to beyond 64 bit collections. How it extends and keeping track of ending positions and such stuff are taken care by the macros.

Every time I need a new run, I need to change the macros. Actually I need to change one macro that sets all the macros. I can't change from `unsigned long long` because all the book keeping has been done for 64bit units, and I have used `ULL` for literals in several places. I am considering replacing all this with `static constexpr` members from a templated  struct, and make it possible to use any `unsigned` as a building block, not just `ull`

These are what I am considering replacing:

```
using myuint = unsigned long long;

// Only reset this for new runs if needed:
#define BASE_DIM 120ULL

#define DIM 64ULL

#if BASE_DIM%DIM==0ULL

  #define N_DIM_IDX ((BASE_DIM)/(DIM))
  #define POS_LAST 63ULL
  #define POS_LAST_IDX (N_DIM_IDX - 1ULL)

#else

  #define N_DIM_IDX ( 1ULL + ((BASE_DIM)/(DIM)) )
  #define POS_LAST ((BASE_DIM%DIM) - 1ULL)
  #define POS_LAST_IDX (N_DIM_IDX - 1ULL)

#endif
```

These are now embedded in countless places in the code, in mission critical parts where speed matters. The following is what I am considering as a replacement:

```
// size in bits. maybe change it as all platform don't necessarily have byte = 8 bits
template<typename U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned<U>::value, int> = 0 >
struct T_bit_size{
  typedef U type;
  static constexpr U value = sizeof(U)*8;
};

template<typename U, U D, typename E = void >
struct details{
  static constexpr bool value     = false;
  static constexpr bool divisible = false;
};

// all bookkeeping here
template<typename U, U D>
struct details<U,D,std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned<U>::value && (D>0) > >{
  static constexpr bool value     = true;
  static constexpr U dim          = D;                                         // Replaces BASE_DIM
  static constexpr U units        = T_bit_size<U>::value;                      // Replaces DIM 
  static constexpr bool divisible = (dim%units == 0);
  typedef U type;

  static constexpr U N_idx       = divisible ? (dim/units) : (dim/units + 1);  // Replaces N_DIM_IDX
  static constexpr U L_idx       = N_idx - 1;                                  // Replaces POS_LAST_IDX
  static constexpr U L_idx_N_pos = divisible ? (units) : (dim%units);          // New!!!
  static constexpr U L_idx_L_pos = L_idx_N_pos - 1;                            // Replaces POS_LAST
};

// one of type U
template<typename U>
struct unsigned_value_of{
  static constexpr U one  = 1;
};
```

As an example in the code this is how I would replace it:

```
//     currently:
class something{
// stuff
/*1)*/ for(myuint k=0; k<=(POS_LAST_IDX); k++)
// stuff
/*2)*/ (stuff)&(1ULL << POS_LAST_IDX)
// stuff
};

//     if replaced:
template<typename U, U D > /* some enable_if for only unsigned enabled*/
class something{
// stuff
/*1)*/ for(U k=0; k<details<U>::N_idx; k++)
// stuff
/*2)*/ (stuff)&(unsigned_value_of<U>::one << details<U>::L_idx_L_pos)
// stuff
};
```

If I do this, it is probably a two day job of doing the replacements carefully and checking I didn't brake anything. If I do replace it well I have a general code. If any further book keeping happens to come up I can add another member in `details`.

Ok so my main question is how is this going to impact performance? Should I expect significant overhead? Should I expect any overhead? Are compiler optimisations going to be silence because of this?

Any comments welcome.

Comment: Regarding the "I didn't break anything" part, it would be simplified by having plenty of unit-tests.

Comment: And if you need to change some parameters "every run" then you should look into configuration files or command-line arguments.

Comment: I should although I do not know hat those are. I will google that. But it all hinges on just one macro replacement. The rest is written based on this macro. So it would be good to eventually change it, with something like the above maybe?

Comment: Considering you seem to be doing a lot of 'stuff' around those macro usages, it is probably ill-invested efforts to try to consider performances for such a small change. There should be an overhead related to using a class whereas there were none prior to the change, but if you do happen to do it, and benchmark the result as well as the current version, you'll probably laugh at the concerns you're currently having. The thing to consider here is mostly the overhead in code size that you can get by using templates. If it happens to be an issue, some tooling can solve it almost completely.